# Value cannot be null message when implementing PropertyChangedEvent

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have this C# code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Threading;
namespace City
{
    public static class MS 
    {

        public static event EventHandler<PropertyChangedEventArgs> StaticPropertyChanged;

        private static void NotifyStaticPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            if (StaticPropertyChanged != null)
                StaticPropertyChanged(null, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }

        private static int timerSeconds;
        public static int TimerSeconds
        {
            get { return timerSeconds; }
            set { timerSeconds = value; NotifyStaticPropertyChanged("TimerSeconds"); }
        }
    }
}
```

and this XAML

```
 <Frame xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" 
  x:Class="City.Test">

 <Label x:Name="timer" Text="{Binding Source={x:Static local:MS.TimerSeconds}}" />
        </Grid>
```

When I compile it gives me a compile error saying:

> Error: Value cannot be null. Parameter name: clrNamespace (City)

Does anyone have any idea what may be causing this.  When I commment out the Label line or when I change to `Text="ABC"` the error goes away

Comment: Just a small thing - you should raise your event like this: `var spc = StaticPropertyChanged; if (spc != null) spc(null, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));`. This is to avoid any potential threading issues in your code. It's a good habit to get in to even if it doesn't apply to this specific code.

Comment: And do you really get this error when you compile or is it when you run your code?

Comment: Or you can use new syntax from C# 6: `StaticPropertyChanged?.Invoke(null, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
`

Comment: @Melina, could you add definiton of your `local` namespace to your question?

Comment: It says "Build: 1 error"

Comment: @Kedrzu - if you put that into an answer I can try that.

Comment: @Kedrzu - I am not sure how to find the definition of that. Could that be a problem as the namespace is City

Comment: Usually on the top of your view/page you have something like: `<ContentPage ... xmlns:local="clr-namespace:HelloWorld" ...>`. In this case you can think of `xmlns:local...` as equivalent to `using HelloWorld;` in C#.

Comment: I would strongly recomend you to not use static class to keep data and bind something to them. Stange things may happen - in your code you are calling event with null sender. Event if it's working right now, it may not work with future releases of Xamarin.Forms. At least use singleton pattern - it allows you to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface.

Comment: @Kedrzu - I am not sure how to implement with the singleton pattern. I will open up a new question and ask about this.  Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You did not define your `local` namespace. You should add namespace: `xmlns:local="clr-namespace:City"`. Change your code to something like this:

```
 <Frame xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" 
  xmlns:local="clr-namespace:City"
  x:Class="City.Test">

 <Label x:Name="timer" Text="{Binding Source={x:Static local:MS.TimerSeconds}}" />
        </Grid>
```

For more information read [this article](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/xaml/namespaces/)